# InDesign script targeting specific text frames

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-indesign

I have an InDesign document with ~550 pages. On an every page, there are 4 frames, all the pages look the same (see image below). I'm using InDesign CS6 and JS.

I need a script that fulfills some rather basic functions, if possible:

1.

- Target text frame (1)
- Delete the text frame

2.

- Target text frame (2)
- Applying a given paragraph style

3.

- Target image frame (4)
- Fit Frame Proportionally
- Do so on all pages

[image: layout]

I tried the following (see below). Somehow, ID tells me "myParagraph.applyParagraphStyle" and "myFrame.fit" is "not a function".

2.

```
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
myParagraph = myDocument.pages.item(1);
myParagraphStyle  = myDocument.paragraphStyles.item('datum');
myParagraph.applyParagraphStyle(myParagraphStyle,true);
```

3.

```
var myDocument = app.activeDocument;
var myGraphic = myDocument.pages.item(3);
var myFrame = myGraphic.parent;
myFrame.fit(FitOptions.proportionally);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the DOM for InDesign. Have a look here:

http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/

> myParagraph = myDocument.pages.item(1);

Paragraphs are not child nodes of pages. Also, I would address one page at the time and loop through pages.

Try:

```
var myParagraph = myDocument.pages[0].textFrames[0].paragraphs[0];
```

Similar problem with graphics. You need to address the container which is graphic parent and then graphic it contains:

```
var myGraphic = myDocument.pages[0].rectangles[0].graphics[0];
```

or

```
var myGraphic = myDocument.pages[0].allGraphics[0].graphics[0];
```

Alternatively, you can use pageItems, instead of textFrames or rectangles

Comment: Could you do me a favor? Just show me how this loop through the pages must look like, since I'm new to scripting and it will take me two hours to make it work.

Comment: Referencing page items via their index is unreliable - it doesn't necessarily guarantee that you'll be targeting the correct page item. To reference the correct page item(s) consider utilizing the [`geometricBounds`](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_PageItem.html) property instead - For instance you can infer the correct page item by checking whether its `y1` and `x1` coordinates are within a given range.

Comment: In this case it worked since every page looked the same. But could you give me an example how your solution works?

Comment: @VHS - [Here](https://paste.ee/p/JhS8L) is an gist of processing each text frame and doing something with it (such as deleting it) based on its  y1 and x1 coordinates. It entails **1.** Looping over each page in the document. **2.** Processing each text frame found on each page via the custom `handleTextFrames` function. **3.** In the body of the `handleTextFrames` function we obtain the text frames page geometry and conditionally do stuff (e.g. delete it) based on it's  `x1` and `y1` coordinate. BTW. When writing a comment to someone you should `@<name>` them otherwise they aren't notified.